# XMPP behind a GCP TCP/SSL proxy load balancer

Tags: load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, xmpp, prosody

I'm trying to set up an XMPP server on Google Compute Engine. I'm currently playing with [Prosody](https://prosody.im). My preferred deployment strategy for servers is to have immutable infrastructure, so I tend to build an image of the server I want (using [Packer](https://packer.io)), create an instance template of it, and create a managed instance group of that instance template with a target size set to 1. This has the benefit of making sure I always have at least one server alive and responding to requests, and automatically recreates the server in the event of an issue. It also means I need to have all my requests go through a load balancer, however, as the server IP isn't stable.

For HTTP/S this isn't an issue, as the HTTP/S load balancers work quite well. For TCP, this is proving to be an issue. [Network Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network/index) requires a list of instances to balance between, which means when my instance is destroyed and recreated, the load balancer is out of date. [TCP Proxy Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp/index) and [SSL Proxy Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl/) don't have this issue, but they have a restricted set of ports that they can be used with. Curiously, 5222 (the reserved port for client-to-server XMPP traffic) is in this whitelisted group of ports, but 5269 (the reserved port for server-to-server XMPP traffic) is not in this whitelist. I'm not sure why Google would allow client-to-server traffic but not server-to-server traffic.

I guess my question is whichever of these I can get an answer to:

- Does Google *actually* block port 5269 on their SSL/TCP proxy load balancers?

  - If yes, why? They allow 5222, which is effectively useless without 5269, I think?
- Is port 5269 actually required for XMPP, or will servers fall back to 5222?
- Is there some strategy I'm missing here for getting TCP traffic on port 5269 to an instance in an instance group?

Comment: At GCP we do not block port 5269 on SSL/TCP proxy load balancers. Have you allowed this port in your firewall ?

Comment: At GCP we only support a very specific set of ports for [TCP Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp/#overview) and [SSL Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl/) load balancers.

If you determines that you need to accept traffic on TCP 5269, then you could use a GCP network load balancer instead.Network load balancers pass traffic on whatever port it's sent; they are not proxies.